# Calibrate Touchscreen

Tags: touchpad, touch-screen

I am having trouble with the calibration of a touch screen for kiosk system. I have install `xinput_calibrator` and executed:

```
$ xinput_calibrator -v
DEBUG: XInputExtension version is 2.3
DEBUG: Skipping virtual master devices and devices without axis valuators.
DEBUG: Skipping device 'Virtual core XTEST pointer' id=4, does not report Absolute events.
DEBUG: Skipping device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse' id=12, does not report Absolute events.
DEBUG: Selected device: MicroTouch Systems, Inc. MicroTouch USB Touchscreen - EX II
DEBUG: Not usbtouchscreen calibrator: Not a usbtouchscreen device
DEBUG: Not evdev calibrator: Evdev: invalid "Evdev Axis Calibration" property format
Calibrating standard Xorg driver "MicroTouch Systems, Inc. MicroTouch USB Touchscreen - EX II"
current calibration values: min_x=0, max_x=65535 and min_y=0, max_y=65535
If these values are estimated wrong, either supply it manually with the --precalib option, or run the 'get_precalib.sh' script to automatically get it (through HAL).
DEBUG: Found that 'MicroTouch Systems, Inc. MicroTouch USB Touchscreen - EX II' is a sysfs name.
DEBUG: Adding click 0 (X=323, Y=768)
DEBUG: Adding click 1 (X=970, Y=766)
DEBUG: Adding click 2 (X=321, Y=253)
DEBUG: Adding click 3 (X=969, Y=247)
--> Making the calibration permanent <--
DEBUG: Found that 'MicroTouch Systems, Inc. MicroTouch USB Touchscreen - EX II' is a sysfs name.
copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf' (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ in some distro's)
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier    "calibration"
  MatchProduct  "MicroTouch Systems, Inc. MicroTouch USB Touchscreen - EX II"
  Option    "MinX"  "10961"
  Option    "MaxX"  "55163"
  Option    "MinY"  "54602"
  Option    "MaxY"  "10485"
  Option    "SwapXY"    "0" # unless it was already set to 1
  Option    "InvertX"   "0"  # unless it was already set
  Option    "InvertY"   "0"  # unless it was already set
EndSection
```

But that does not change the miscalibration of the screen and I guess I need to make use of the `xinput_calibrator --precalib` option, since the generated values are wrong.

How can I obtain those values to put in that command?

**UPDATE**

Due to the comments, here some more details:

1. The output above is saved in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf`
2. Please find the relevant parts of content of the file `.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` before and after the configuration above was applied [->here<-](https://pastebin.com/sPscgqJ3)

Comment: What file did you copy the `Section...EndSection` into? When you restart the X server what does it say about it in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or similar?

Comment: please see my updates…

Comment: So it seems to read your file. I don't know what to suggest. There may be an alternative mechanism [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation).

Answer (score 0):

xinput_calibrator is for calibrating touchscreens using evdev. The driver used for your touchscreen is libinput. So you need to use the Options CalibrationMatrix or TransformationMatrix.